# How to add the result of 2 selects from different databases in TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to sum a field in rows in 2 tables in diffrent databases in a stored procedure
and return result.

I will pass in the name of the  database and the other will be the current DB.

Say the table is called PayrollLedgers and the field is PLAmount. The passed in DB name is tbr0910. And also I want to filter both tables by PLEmpID passed in to sp.

Can you please supply the TSQL for this?
I do have TSQL experience but this has me stumped.

Comment: Even tho this might work; This is horrible. / Runs off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use dynamic SQL for this.  Generate the SQL statement and run it using sp_executesql.

```
CREATE proc getsomevalue
    @otherdbname sysname,
    @PLEmpID int
as
declare @sql nvarchar(4000) -- this is a short statement, max is not needed
set @sql = '
    select @result =
    (select isnull(sum(PLAmount),0) from PayrollLedgers
    where PLEmpID=@PLEmpID)
    +
    (select isnull(sum(PLAmount),0) from ['+@otherdbname+']..PayrollLedgers
    where PLEmpID=@PLEmpID)'
declare @sum float
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@PLEmpID int,@result float output', @PLEmpID, @sum output

select @sum
GO
```

To replicate this using the exact object names as shown, create it in tempdb then run it with

```
use tempdb
exec getsomevalue 'tbr0910', 1
```

After creating the below objects

```
create database tbr0910
GO
use tbr0910
create table PayrollLedgers(PLEmpID int, PLAmount int)
insert PayrollLedgers select 1,2
insert PayrollLedgers select 1,4
insert PayrollLedgers select 3,4
GO
use tempdb
create table PayrollLedgers(PLEmpID int, PLAmount int)
insert PayrollLedgers select 1,2
insert PayrollLedgers select 1,4
insert PayrollLedgers select 3,4
```

Comment: @Malcolm then you must be using SQL 2000. Just change it to nvarchar(4000)

Comment: @Malcolm - updated to nvarchar(4000) for SQL Server 2000, as Conrad has already pointed out

Comment: Have you transcribed any object names? I've added my test table creations.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this three ways

1) Dynamic SQL approach as provide by cyberkiwi

2) Assuming SQL 2005 or later create a [Synonym](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) and then change the synonym when you need (there are concurrency issues here so you need to be careful)

3) Call two sum one on each of the two data sources and then add them together in your client. This is probably the most sensible approach  since its usually trivial to change the SQL connection string, but doesn't answer your question.